# How to retrieve data from Yahoo Finance to my website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, yahoo-finance

I am making an ASP.NET website where I want to retrieve data from Yahoo Finance, e.g.:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=RHT+MSFT&f=sb2b3jk

I am referring to above link to fetch data from Yahoo Finance.

The above link gives data in CSV format.

So how can I fetch data from the above link into my website? Any code or reference to some tutorial would be of great help.

Comment: Regularly ie. nightly batch process? On demand per click?

Comment: I want data from yahoo finance every 1 min. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer.

Used **System.Net.WebRequest** to download the CSV and then parsed it using answer in below link.

[How to parse a CSV file in an ASP.NET website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748118/asp-net-how-to-parse-the-csv-file-in-an-asp-net-website/4769348#4769348)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to request the CSV, then something like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) to parse the file into a usable object. Then stuff into whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am a newbie into this. So will you please give a more detailed information about using this System.Net.WebClient to request and access the CSV file and Also throw some light on FileHelpers.

Comment: Follow the links -- they have examples throughout.