# How to parse a CSV file in an ASP.NET website?

Tags: .net, parsing, csv

In my website, I have many CSV files that I need to parse and insert their data into my MySQL database.

How can I parse the CSV in my website programmatically?

Comment: Very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748082/how-to-download-the-csv-file-in-my-website-from-other-webserver. Only a few words different.

Comment: The other post is about downloading, not parsing.

Comment: this has nothing to do with asp.net, it's only about parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the Answer:**

I have successfully done the parsing of my CSV file using the below code:

```
_nNrRowsProccessed = 0;

    string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq="+ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["csvFolder"]+";";

    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string strFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["csvFileName"];
        string strSQL = "Select * from " + strFileName;

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strLine = null;

        MasterCalendar_DB.OpenMySQLConnection();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // insert data into mastercalendar
            strLine = reader[0].ToString();
            string[] arLine = strLine.Split(';');

            string strAgencyPropertyID = arLine[0];
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(arLine[1]);
            Int64 nDate = (Int64)Util.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(dt);
            String strAvailability = (arLine[2]);

            _nNrRowsProccessed++;
            MasterCalendar_DB.Insert(strAgencyPropertyID, nDate, strAvailability);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        MasterCalendar_DB.CloseMySQLConnection();
    }
```

**Also you need to add the following code under Configurations tag into your web.config file:**

`<appSettings>
   <add key="csvFileName" value="<file_name>.csv" />
   <add key="csvFolder" value="<filePath>"/>
   </appSettings>`

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 6):

I recommend looking at the [TextFieldParserClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx) in .Net. You need to include

```vb
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
```

Here's a quick sample:

```vb
Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(FileName)
Dim CurrentRecord As String() ' this array will hold each line of data
afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
afile.Delimiters = New String() {","}
afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

' parse the actual file
Do While Not afile.EndOfData
    Try
        CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
    Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
        Stop
    End Try
Loop
```