# Removing a comma within double quotes, then remove double quotes

Tags: c#, csv, entity, delimiter, filehelpers

I'm having issues with creating a delimiter field using FileHelpers when parsing a .csv. I have this one line of data that is always crashing during a LINQ operation similar to the example of the filehelpers on their site.

The error comes up at where a column has quotes such as this row:

data1, data2, "data3a, data3b", data4

How do I remove the comma within the quotes and then remove the quotes for data3a and data3b?

That specific column in the .csv file has two things, but I can't figure what delimiter fields I should use for that.

If I'm unclear or this question was answered or not purposeful comment below.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
The code for the class

The row: 2010,NON-HISPANIC BLACK,MALE,"NEPHRITIS, NEPHROTIC SYNDROME AND NEPHROSIS",70,1

```
//delimiters, ignore first row, separate with comma
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst()]
public class CauseofDeathClass
{

    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Cause_of_Death { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your code and where it's going wrong?

Comment: I added the class code, the code for going through the .csv file is similar to the example for delimiters on filehelpers.com

Comment: [Reading a CSV file in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-a-csv-file-in-net)

Comment: [How to parse a CSV file in an ASP.NET website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748118/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-in-an-asp-net-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `FieldQuoted` attribute. See [here](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_QuoteMode.htm) for the different QuoteMode options.

```
//delimiters, ignore first row, separate with comma
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst()]
public class CauseofDeathClass
{    
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string Cause_of_Death { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }
}
```